# Error starting AppName Module 'AppName' attempts to access a secure API

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

In my BB application after installing it on the device showing this Error **"Error starting AppName Module 'AppName' attempts to access a secure API"**

I am opening internet Browser in my application and not giving any kind of permission so this can be the reason of this error of something else.....

Please Help
Thanks

Comment: thats because of the code signing problem. you didnt properly signed the code

Comment: Yes i signed the Code but no check is there any way to check code is signed or not.?

Comment: refer this http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/BlackBerry-Applications-and-code-signing-Start-to-Finish/ta-p/445848

Comment: App is working simply but when a add this line on Button Clicked->        Browser.getDefaultSession().displayPage(url);

it start this error again and without this link app working good so i just want to know i need to take any kind of permission for Browser Opening.????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try to sign your application, then install. If you do not have a signature key, you can request new keys [here](https://developer.blackberry.com/android/documentation/Bar_signing_1904696_11.html). It's free nowadays. More help in this [link](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/BlackBerry-Applications-and-code-signing-Start-to-Finish/ta-p/445848).

Comment: I signed my App as i know please let me know is there any way to check code sign .?

Comment: Load signature tools from bin directory and open you code file. if your application signed then green message will display "Signed".

Comment: I found and Completed but after importing file from Blackberry Desktop manager its showing. No Additional application found. YOur file migth contains application that already exist in the Application list..... 
please help

Comment: Please see on bin directory on install JDE . On my computer this path i can found. C:\Program Files (x86)\Research In Motion\BlackBerry JDE 7.1.0\bin\SignatureTool.jar

Comment: App is working simply but when a add this line on Button Clicked-> Browser.getDefaultSession().displayPage(url); it start this error again and without this link app working good so i just want to know i need to take any kind of permission for Browser Opening.????

Comment: have you sign on not?. please sign then resolve your problem. what's problem you have to sign?. It's batter to install app on device with sign. i have not idea which api require sing.

Comment: App is working simply but when a add this line on Button Clicked-> Browser.getDefaultSession().displayPage(url); it start this error again and without this link app working good so i just want to know i need to take any kind of permission for Browser Opening.????

Answer (score 3):

This error indicates that the application has not been fully signed.  Note that when you sign up for a set of code signing keys for BlackBerry OS 7.1 and lower you are sent 3 different keys.  All 3 must be installed.  If you don't install all of them you could partially sign your application and receive the error above.

You can verify the signatures applied to a COD file by opening the COD file using the SignatureTool.  It'll show the signatures that have been applied.  Look for signatures for RBB, RCR and RRT (note that RRT is only present when required).

Comment: App is working simply but when a add this line on Button Clicked-> Browser.getDefaultSession().displayPage(url); it start this error again and without this link app working good so i just want to know i need to take any kind of permission for Browser Opening.????