# Error APPNAME module attempts to access a secure API when trying to start BlackBerry app on some devices

Tags: blackberry, java-me, code-signing

Our client is reporting when they try to start the app on their testing devices, the following error message appears:

[image: App Error]

I searched for the error, found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11361182/error-starting-appname-module-appname-attempts-to-access-a-secure-api) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8090068/blackberry-error-module-attempts-to-access-secure-api) and it's mentioned this is caused when the code sign process is faulty.

From what I understand, if the code signing process fails, then the app shouldn't be able to run on any device, but the ones we have have no problem running the app at all.

The app is built with BlackBerry SDK 6.0 and we have tested on both a BlackBerry 9360 with OS version 7.1 Bundle 2102 (v.7.1.0.746, Platform 9.6.0.112) and a BlackBerry 9800 with OS 6.0 Bundle 1907 (v6.0.0.448, Platform 6.4.0.210). Both devices can run the app. The client is testing on another BlackBerry 9360 but I don't have the OS specifications at the moment, but already requested them.

I have installed the app through the BlackBerry Desktop Software, Eclipse's Debug As BlackBerry Device option and Eclipse's Load Project(s) on Device option.

The client uses BlackBerry Desktop Software to install the app on their testing device.

What can cause for the app to run fine on our devices but not on the ones the client uses?
Is the problem related to the code signing keys?

**EDIT**

The client shared with us the following device information:

`BlackBerry 9900 7.1 bundle 1909 v7.1.0.658 platform 5.1.0.485`

Are there any issues for this device with this specific or similar bundle setting?

Also another strange thing the client reported when we were talking to them was that when they went to the route in Options -> Device -> Application Manager, when accesing the app details and then Edit Permissions, they reported although permissions were present, no modules for the app were shown, I double checked on my side and when I install the app from Eclipse (either through the Debug As... option or the Load Project(s) on Device option) the app shows the modules but when installed through the BlackBerry Desktop Software the modules appear hidden, in both cases I can run the app on both devices we own. Is this normal? Can this affect certain devices and make them not run the app?

**EDIT 2**

I ran the signature tool by executing the jar and it shows the code signing process to be completed with no failed required or failed optional signatures. I attach the image displaying this:

[image: Code Signing Success]

Comment: I don't think it is a signing keys issue. If keys were incorrect you was not able to sign the cod file(s) without errors. I think the problem is related to this particular device. Is that possible that there's an installed policy exist on the device? or is some parts of the device functionality somehow blocked by a BlackBerry Enterprise Server administrator ?

Comment: I'm not that knowledgeable on BlackBerry particular issues, could you explain how can I check the installed policies? How can I tell if a functionality is being blocked by a blackberry Enterprise Server administrator? This problem forced me to make a build with SDK 6 and another with SDK 7.

Comment: if I understand you correctly the problem is not related to SDK version. It is related to a particular actual device. Read about policies here: http://btsc.webapps.blackberry.com/btsc/viewdocument.do;jsessionid=7F6172269D59B486E9C423EB59B060DC?externalId=KB14202&sliceId=2&cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&noCount=true&ViewedDocsListHelper=com.kanisa.apps.common.BaseViewedDocsListHelperImpl

Comment: the thing is, if I make load a version of the app built with SDK 7.0 then the app will run with no problem on their devices, but an install built with SDK 6.0 will show the error message I posted.

The link you supplied refers to removing a device from a BlackBerry Enterprise Server, which I doubt is my case since this app is open to the public (that's what I get from the BB Enterprise Server definition, I'm not that knowledgeable about BlackBerry stuff).

Comment: If it works ok on SDK 7, and produces a problem with SDK 6, then there is a problem related with this particular SDK version. I see the following options. 1. Check for newer SDK 6 version (look at all numbers in the SDK version number) than yours. Maybe it does exist. Check it here: http://developer.blackberry.com/bbos/java/   2. If nothing helps, and it is applicable from user experience point of view use SDK 5 to compile apps for devices with BB OS version 6. 3. Contact BlackBerry developer support via: devsupport@rim.com

Comment: I have the latest SDK 6.0, SDK 7.0 and SDK 7.1 versions, we have a BB 9360 with OS 7.1 and we have no problem running the app, on the other hand the client´s test devices: a BlackBerry 9720 7.1 bundle 2839 v7.1.0.1046 platform 9.105.0.16, a BlackBerry 9900 7.1 bundle 1909 v7.1.0.658 platform 5.1.0.485 and a BlackBerry 9860 7.1 bundle 1909 v7.1.0.658  platform 5.1.0.485 all three can't run the app if it's built with SDK 6.0. Keep in mind the app is not for OS 5 due to the client requirements, the target audience is 6.x and 7.x only.

Comment: In this case the only option left from my point of view. Contact BlackBerry Developer Support at devsupport@rim.com and post a question on the official dev. support forum: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/tkb-p/java_dev%40tkb  there are BlackBerry staff registered and I think it should help with your issue.

Comment: I've already performed both of your recommendations.

Contacting BlackBerry Developer Support hasn't changed anything, I haven't gotten a reply in 2 weeks and I don't if I should send more emails because I fear they might block me or something.

The forums hasn't produced results and I try to keep the thread alive but no useful response so far.

I don't know where else to turn at this point.

Comment: SDK bugs are hard to overcome, but as an option, try to find out which your class and then which method, and then which code line leads to this problem. Step by step, replace your classes with empty stubs, then compile, sign and deploy application to the "problem" device. If the problem is gone, then return all classes, except the last one replaced with the empty stub. Then try again to compile and deploy. If the problem is gone, you have found the problem class. Use the same approach to find the "bad" method. Then analyze the logic of the found "bad" code and try to rewrite it.